# setIcon for tabLayout is putting the icon above the text, not below it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tablayout

So here's the dependencies that are causing the problem in build.grade:

The not working code here:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Working code here:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

The working code is actually older than the newer one as you can see. Here is what I am trying to get at.

With the non-working code, the icons are showing above the text like this:

[Non working layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd5lc.png)

and with the working code, it is like this (which is how I want it to show):

[Working layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekn7k.png)

Is there anyway to make the icons show in the second image with using the "non working code"?

NOTE: I am using tabLayout and I am setting the icons like this:

```
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_action_add,
        R.drawable.ic_action_gear
};

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
```

and I am setting the text on the tabs like this:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFragment(), "Add");
    adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFeedFragment(), "Settings");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can not use latest support library until update you `buildToolsVersion "23.2.1"` to latest one.. this will solve your first problem...
- for icon related problem may be your image size is cause of problem..

Comment: Your icon related problem you can show us your image , that would be helpful for better understand..

Comment: I linked the image: "Non working layout" and "Working layout"

Comment: now you have a working layout. that means your problem is solved ? right?